Brezis's Exercise 6.9.3
I'm looking to prove the following statement:

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces. Let $L(E,F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$. Consider the set of all operators $T\in L(E,F)$ such that $\dim(N(T)) < \infty$ and $R(T)$ is closed. Prove that this set is open in $L(E,F)$.

This is part 3 of the following problem:

Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces. Let $L(E,F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$, and $K(E,F)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $T \in L(E, F)$. We denote by $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ the range and kernel of $T$.

Prove that the following properties are equivalent:

(A) $\dim(N(T))< \infty$ and $R(T)$ is closed.
(B) There exist a constant $C>0$ and a finite-rank operator $P \in L(E)$
such that $P=P^2$ and $|u|_E \leq C(|Tu|_F+|Pu|_E)$
for all $u \in E$.
(C) There exist a Banach space $G$, an operator $Q \in K(E,G)$, and a constant $C>0$ such that $|u|_E \leq C(|Tu|_F+|Qu|_G)$ for all $u \in E$.

Assume that $T$ satisfies (A). Prove that $(T+S)$
also satisfies (A) for every $S \in K(E, F)$.

Prove that the set of all operators $T \in L(E, F)$
satisfying (A) is open in $L(E, F)$.

Let $F_0$ be a closed linear subspace of $F$ and let $S \in K(F_0, F)$. Prove that $R(I+S)$ is closed. Here $I$ is the identity map.



Here is my approach: Define $U = \{ T \in L(E, F) : T \text{ satisfies } (A) \}$.
I have explored three different possible solutions, with no luck.

Choose $T \in L(E, F)$ such that $T$ satisfies (A).
I hope there exists $r > 0$ such that $|A| < r \Rightarrow A \in K(E, F)$.
If this is true, then for any $S \in B(T, r)$, note $S - T \in K(E, F)$.
Thus, by question 6.9.2, $S = T + (S - T)$ satisfies (A).

We show $L(E, F) \backslash U$ is closed.
Let $(S_n)$ be a sequence in $L(E, F) \backslash U$.
Suppose $(S_n)$ converges to $S$.
Somehow, we show that either $\dim(N(S)) = \infty$ or $R(S)$ is not closed.

Choose $T \in L(E, F)$ such that $T$ satisfies (A).
Somehow, there exists $r > 0$ and finite rank operator $P_r \in L(E)$, such that $P_r = P_r^2$ and
$$ r|u|_E + |Pu|_E \leq |P_r u|_E . $$
As a result, for any $S \in B(T, r)$,
$$ |u|_E≤C(|Tu|_F+|Pu|_E) \leq C(r|u|_E + |Su|_F + |Pu|_E) \leq C(|Su|_F + |P_r u|_E) . $$


Which strategy would be most promising to pursue, or is there a different direction I should go entirely? Any help would be much appreciated!

What's your question?

If you quotient out the kernel of some map $T$ with property (A), you get an injective map that has closed range. Such maps are bounded below. If you perturb this by some operator with norm less than the bound you get a new operator with property (A). Thus the set is open.

Suppose $T\in L(E,F)$ satisfies condition (A). By part 1 it is sufficient to show there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $T+S$ satisfies condition (B) whenever $S\in L(E,F)$ with $\|S\| < \delta$. Since $N(T)$ is finite-dimensional and finite-dimensional subspaces have a topological complement, there exists some closed subspace $M$ of $E$ such that $E = N(T) \oplus M$. Let $P$ be the projection of $E$ onto $N(T)$ such that $N(P) = M$. Because $N(T)$ and $M$ are both closed subspaces and $N(T)$ is finite-dimensional it follows that $P$ is a finite-rank bounded linear operator on $E$.
Note that the restriction of $T$ to $M$ is an injective bounded linear operator with closed range, so the restriction is bounded below and consequently there is some $\delta >0$ such that $\delta |u|_{E} \leq |Tu|_{F}$ for all $u\in M$. Such a $\delta$ will be fixed throughout the rest of this proof. If $S\in L(E,F)$, you have that
\begin{equation}
|(T+S)u|_{F} \geq |Tu|_{F} - |Su|_{F} \geq \delta |u|_{E} - \|S\| |u|_{E} = (\delta - \|S\|) |u|_{E}
\end{equation}
holds for all $u\in M$. As a result, the condition $S\in L(E,F)$ with $\|S\| < \delta$ implies that
\begin{equation}
|u|_{E} \leq (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)u|_{F} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for all $u\in M$.
Let $S\in L(E,F)$ with $\|S\| < \delta$. Let $u\in E$. Since $R(P) \subseteq N(T)$ and (1) is valid for all $u\in M = R(I-P)$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
|u|_{E} &\leq |(I-P)u|_{E} + |Pu|_{E} \\
&\leq (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)(I-P)u|_{F} + |Pu|_{E} \\
&\leq (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)u|_{F} + (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)Pu|_{E} + |Pu|_{E} \\
&= (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)u|_{F} + (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|SPu|_{F} + |Pu|_{E} \\
&\leq (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}|(T+S)u|_{F} + ((\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}\|S\| + 1) |Pu|_{E} \\
&\leq \max\{(\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}, (\delta - \|S\|)^{-1}\|S\| + 1 \}(|(T+S)u|_{F} + |Pu|_{E}).
\end{align*}
This shows that $T+S$ satisfies condition (B) and proves the result by applying part 1.
Note that the first approach you tried wouldn't work because $K(E,F)$ is a proper closed subspace of $L(E,F)$ when $E$ is infinite-dimensional, so $K(E,F)$ would have empty interior in $L(E,F)$ when that is the case.

Thank you for this quick and thoughtful response. It seems involved enough to warrant an answer in the back of the book, but I suppose Brezis didn't think so!
